# How create circular image using only percentages in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

**When I m trying to make circular image using only percentages it just fails.**

***Why I want that?*** because it would allow me to create greatly modular functions to handle size of my element, and make them responsive in the same time.

**Here my sandbox**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kkbyff

**here my reactjs snippet:**

```
const generateStyle=(sizeReference)=>{
  let unity="%" // FAIL TO MAKE CIRCULE WHEN I USE PERCENTAGES HERE
  // console.log(sizeReference+unity)
  return {
    height:sizeReference+unity,
    width:sizeReference+unity,
    borderRadius:(sizeReference/2)+unity
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="photo_slider">
      <div className="pic1">
        <img 
          src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/Nduz52P.jpg" 
          alt="awesome_image"
          style={generateStyle(30)}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="pic2">
        <img 
          src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/5MsoNXS.jpg" 
          alt="awesome_image"
          style={generateStyle(15)}
          />
      </div>
      <div className="pic3">
        <img 
          src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/Nduz52P.jpg" 
          alt="awesome_image"
          style={generateStyle(80)}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="pic4">
        <img 
          src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/5MsoNXS.jpg" 
          alt="awesome_image"
          style={generateStyle(35)}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="pic5">
        <img 
          src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/Nduz52P.jpg" 
          alt="awesome_image"
          style={generateStyle(60)}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.photo_slider{ 
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: beige;
}
```

How make circular image using only percentages?

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: have you tried setting the `borderRadius` to the fixed value `50%`?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you just want all images appear as circles.

Change this

```
borderRadius:(sizeReference/2)+unity
```

to this

```
borderRadius: "50%"
```

For true circle use only sizeReference for width and height.

Comment: thanks, it returns me some ovalishes forms, how it is on your browser please?

Comment: This *sort-of* works, but the problem is that the boxes are not square, so you end up with ovals, not circles. @Webwoman because your sizes are not perfect squares, you cannot make them circles; it doesn't make sense.

Comment: If you want circles remove unity and just use sizeReference for height and width.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have tried and it fails, what do you mean, can you precise please? I have tried this meanwhile: https://codepen.io/joondoe/pen/QReBgY, transforming my image in square before making them circle, but it fails with percentages

Comment: If you do only height:sizeReference, width:sizeReference there always be a circle because of the same dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

**Going the `css` way**
Since a non-square image will not form a circle even with `borderRadius: "50%"`
The best way to achieve this is to place the image inside a square container and declare `borderRadius: "50%"; overflow: "hidden"` on the container.